# Invalid number error in reading data from external table in Oracle 11gr2

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

I am having the below DDL for external table.

```
CREATE TABLE emp_load
  (
     employee_number      VARCHAR2(50),
     employee_last_name   VARCHAR2(50),
     employee_first_name  VARCHAR2(50),
     employee_middle_name VARCHAR2(50),
     employee_hire_date   VARCHAR2(50)
  )
organization external (TYPE oracle_loader DEFAULT directory abc_dir ACCESS
                      parameters ( records
                      delimited BY newline fields terminated BY '|' missing
                      field VALUES are NULL (employee_number, employee_last_name
                      , employee_first_name, employee_middle_name,
                      employee_hire_date) ) location ('info.dat') ) reject limit
                      UNLIMITED
```

and my .dat file is like below.

```
010|ABC|DEF|XYZ|03-DEC-2011
020|CCC|123|SSS|04-DEC-2011
```

I have a table called

```
CREATE TABLE test_emp_load_1
  (
     mployee_number       VARCHAR2(50),
     employee_last_name   VARCHAR2(50),
     employee_first_name  NUMBER(38),
     employee_middle_name VARCHAR2(50),
     employee_hire_date   VARCHAR2(50)
  )
```

and now i am using the below merge statement ( in the below even though i keep e.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER = '020' i think first it trying to run a scan on the entire external table)

which is giving the below error.

SQL Error: ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEFETCH callout
ORA-01722: invalid number

but when i am using

```
MERGE INTO  test_emp_load_1 te
USING (select * from emp_load where EMPLOYEE_NUMBER = '020') e
on ( e.EMPLOYEE_FIRST_NAME = te.employee_first_name  )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET
te.employee_last_name = e.EMPLOYEE_LAST_NAME
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT
(te.employee_last_name)
VALUES
( e.EMPLOYEE_LAST_NAME)
where e.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER = '020';
```

I am getting output  1 row merged. It  looks a bug in Oracle 11g R2.

I am using DB Oracle 11G R2 on Windows Platform. I also tried this in Red hat Linux and Oracle 11g R2 I am getting the same issue

Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, why do you have a name defined as:     employee_first_name  number(38)?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem; but in the same vein; why do you have an EMPLOYEE_NUMBER declared as VARCHAR2(50)? And, you also have an MLOYEE_NUMBER, which is going to be your next error...

Comment: I have am having two table one is having varchar and another is number one corresponding to 010 and other corresponding to 020

Comment: That still doesn't really make sense, but it's the `emoloyee_first_name` field that has the problem, not the `employee_number`. Look at your sample data again. You have a row with the third field as `DEF` and you're trying to compare that in your merge's `on` clause as `number(38)`. You're getting a pefectly reasonable error back, not seeing a bug.

Answer (score 1):

In your external table you have:

```
       employee_first_name  VARCHAR2(50),
```

In your other table you have:

```
       employee_first_name  number(38),
```

In your merge you have:

```
on ( e.EMPLOYEE_FIRST_NAME = te.employee_first_name  )
```

So you're comparing a string with a number. They have to be compared as the same type; it could go either way, but Oracle is choosing to convert the string into a number to do the comparision, so it's effectively doing:

```
on ( to_number(e.EMPLOYEE_FIRST_NAME) = te.employee_first_name  )
```

If your data is actually numeric then that is OK, though it would be better to have the data types right in the first place. But your data is not numeric, and probably isn't really meant to be. Look at your sample data again:

```
010|ABC|DEF|XYZ|03-DEC-2011
020|CCC|123|SSS|04-DEC-2011
```

The 'first name' is the third field in the file. The second row is OK as `'123'` can be converted to a number. The first row is not OK, `'DEF'` cannot be converted to a number. That row is therefore rejected. This probably isn't the field you meant to be numeric in the first place though, given its name.

As Ben mentioned you have the `mployee_number` field named incorrectly in your normal table, so that will also error at some point. Just to avoid those errors your table would need to be defined like this:

```
create table test_emp_load_1 (employee_number NUMBER,
          employee_last_name   VARCHAR2(50),
           employee_first_name  VARCHAR2(50),
          employee_middle_name VARCHAR2(50),
           employee_hire_date   DATE)
```

Assuming all the records will actually have a numeric first field, and a valid date as the last field. Your external table definition should also define the columns with the correct type, and specify the expected date format so that doesn't error. You should always use the correct data types: never store numbers or dates as strings, even in an external table definition (though they are obviously string in the actual external file).

The merge also seems odd as you're only setting the last name for inserted records.